# Laravel how to load a view blade and use it with `DOMDocument`?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel, domdocument

In a case I have multiple views, and in a loop I should pass data to those view and load it, after that I need to parse the loaded view with `DOMDocument()` and write those to specific cell of excel. I have tried bellow steps, but has problem.

```
 foreach($data as $result_row){
     $result_path = Config::get('auditConfig.result_page.'.$result_row['_type']);
     $view = View::make($result_path, array('item' => $result_row));
     $content = $view->render();

     $doc = new \DOMDocument();
     $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
     $doc->loadHTMLFile($content);
     $table_tr = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tr');
     foreach($table_tr as $n) {
        echo $n->nodeValue;
     }
}
```

Comment: what problem or error you are facing ?

Comment: @AlankarMore some thing like DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity `&quot;&lt;table class=&quot;table table-striped&quot;&gt; &lt;thead&gt; &lt;/thead&gt; &lt;tbody&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td&gt;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see the definition of the function `loadHTMLFile`

> public bool DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile ( string $filename [, int $options = 0 ] )

**first parameter is the `$filename` that means the path of the file you want to read**

In your case you are providing the content of the view file instead of the file path of that view.

Let's say you have view as users.blade.php then you will provide the path as follow:

`$doc->loadHTMLFile(app_path('Views/Users/users.blade.php'));`

OR

`$viewFile = app_path('Views/Users/users.blade.php');
$doc->loadHTMLFile($viewFile);`

So as per this your code will be change as follow

```
foreach ($data as $result_row) {
    $result_path = Config::get('auditConfig.result_page.' . $result_row['_type']);

    //$view = View::make($result_path, array('item' => $result_row));
    //$content = $view->render();

    $viewFile = app_path($result_path);

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($viewFile);
    $table_tr = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    foreach ($table_tr as $n) {
        echo $n->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

By reading as string.

```
foreach ($data as $result_row) {
    $result_path = Config::get('auditConfig.result_page.' . $result_row['_type']);

    $view = View::make($result_path, array('item' => $result_row))->__toString();
    //$content = $view->render();

    $viewFile = app_path($result_path);

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadHTML($view);
    $table_tr = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    foreach ($table_tr as $n) {
        echo $n->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about data if I want to pass to the `users.blade.php`? It means the view should be processed with data that I have passed and then I should use that.

Comment: you can use DOMDocument::loadHTML() function. with your old code

Comment: Means If I want to change content of view dynamically with data, then I can not use it with DOMDocument?

Comment: And one another question, can I loop through `$n` to get `td` of each `tr`?